# Windbg: Meaning of ChildEBP and RetAddr

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, assembly, windbg

In WinDbg, the `k` or `kb` command unwinds the stack and produces a stack trace. The output looks like this-

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0021b2f0 559fdbf2 04b885a0 02a30000 5a675a79 <some_symbol>
0021b3dc 559fc3b8 02a3d0b8 0021b4c0 00000000 <some_symbol>
```

As far as I know, EBP is the base pointer which points to the starting address of the current stack-frame. And `RetAddr` is the "return address" where processing will resume once the current function returns. But, according to what I know, the function frames are pushed on the stack. So, why are the values of `RetAddr` significantly different from the values of `ChildEBP`? They should have been similar since we are working on the same stack. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: You are mixing up two different things. RetAddr points to the next piece of actual code that is going to be executed when the current piece of code returns. ChildEBP points to the stack frame that has been set up *by* a piece of code, in essence, just a reference to a (stack) of memory. [Following tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6470/Debug-Tutorial-Part-2-The-Stack) might be a bit outdated but I found it helpfull.

Comment: Thanks! The tutorial helped.

Answer (score 1):

The place where EBP refers to is the really the Data sections of the memory. You can read and write to it.

Where as, the the return address would point to the code sections of the memory. This portion is read-only.

Yes its the same stack but two different portions of the memory. Imagine if you could write to the code portions - it would have been very easy for a hacker to inject malicious code in the code segment.

This [link](http://www.beingdeveloper.com/memory-layout-of-a-program/) has related details